# Query HQL con inner join para rango de fechas

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

Estoy intentando plasmar la siguiente Query de mysql en un proyecto Java donde necesito hacer una NamedQuery igual para buscar en la BD.

```sql
select * from ESTACION, OBSERVACION
WHERE ESTACION.INDICATIVO = OBSERVACION.ID_ESTACION
and OBSERVACION.FECHA >= '2019-04-11' AND OBSERVACION.FECHA <= '2019-04-13'
AND ESTACION.ID_LOCALIDAD=44;
```

De momento he llegado hasta aquí:

```
SELECT o FROM Observacion o inner join on Estacion oe where o.observacionPK.fecha = :fecha BETWEEN :fecha and ....
```

Alguna idea?
gracias!